# Rails 3: API PUT request fails, record not updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, put

I have an application with an API to update artists and a client that tries to interact with the API to update an artist. The problem is that whenever I try to do a PUT request, the record is not updated and the request fails with a `Completed 204 No Content in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)` error.

Here is the API controller:

```
class Api::V1::ArtistsController < Api::V1::BaseController
  respond_to :json

  def show
    respond_with Artist.find_by_id(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    artist = Artist.find_by_id(params[:id])
    respond_with artist.update_attributes(params[:artist])
  end
end
```

The method that makes the API call from the client model:

```
def update_artist_attributes
  self.class.put("/api/artists/#{self.artist_id}.json", { body: {
    artist: {
      bio: self.artist_attributes_copy[:bio],
      phone_number: self.artist_attributes_copy[:phone_number],
      country: self.artist_attributes_copy[:country],
      city: self.artist_attributes_copy[:city]
    }
  } })
end
```

And the server logs (API side):

```
Started PUT "/api/artists/1.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-02 19:00:00 +0100
Processing by Api::V1::ArtistsController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"artist"=>{"bio"=>"NERVO sisters are not lesbians and they're hot! And they're single too!", "phone_number"=>"218391", "country"=>"Afghanistan", "city"=>"dnajksakd"}, "id"=>"1"}
  Artist Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "artists".* FROM "artists" WHERE "artists"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Artist Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "artists" WHERE "artists"."access_token" = 'EqHG8SGh9ldl3W-U5PBECw' LIMIT 1
  Artist Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "artists" WHERE (LOWER("artists"."access_token") = LOWER('EqHG8SGh9ldl3W-U5PBECw') AND "artists"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
  Artist Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "artists" WHERE ("artists"."email" IS NULL AND "artists"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 204 No Content in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The 204 problem is occurring because `update_attributes` does not return the model instance. You want your update method to be:

```
artist = Artist.find_by_id(params[:id])
artist.update_attributes(params[:artist])
respond_with artist
```

Answer (score 1):

`update_attributes` returns either `true`or `false` depending on the success of the operation.

You pass this result to `respond_with`, so i think this is why you get a 204 code ("no content") - the request is considered successfull whatever the result of `update_attributes`, but returns no content.

Answer (score 0):

The two answers submitted are valid but the core of the problem was that I had validation errors, so the model object was not getting updated...