# Ember insert record with multiple relationships - not working

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've been stuck on this problem for two days now, and have not been able to find a solution online. I am hoping some of you might be able to help.

I've got the following models:

```
App.Project = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    project_teams: DS.hasMany('projectTeam')
});

App.ProjectTeam = DS.Model.extend({
    sde_effort: DS.attr('number'),
    project: DS.belongsTo('project'),
    team: DS.belongsTo('team')
});

App.Team = DS.Model.extend({
    project_teams: DS.hasMany('projectTeam'),
    name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

---

And the following code in my projectsController:

```
var project = store.createRecord('project', {
                name: projectName
            });

            project.save().then(function(projectRecord){
                var teamHookerUpper = function(teamId, sdeEffort, idx){
                    store.find('team', teamId).then(function(team){
                        var project_team = store.createRecord('project_team', {
                            project: projectRecord,
                            sde_effort: sdeEffort,
                            team: team
                        });
                        console.log('project team has been created');
                        project_team.save().then(function(pt){
                            projectTeamIds.push(pt.get('id'));
                            if(idx == sdeHeads.length - 1){
                                console.log(projectRecord);
                                projectRecord.set('project_teams', projectTeamIds);
                                projectRecord.save();
                            }
                        });

                    });
                }

                for(var i = 0; i < sdeHeads.length; i++){
                    teamHookerUpper(teamIds[i], sdeHeads[i], i);
                }
            });
```

The logic is the following:

Get the value from a txt in the front end and create a new `Project`. When  you create the project, select all teamIds and sdeEfforts (a metadata value) associated with that project, create multiple `TeamProject` objects and link them to the newly created `Project`. The `Team` value associated with ProjectTeam is just an id and I am able to retrieve the object by making a call to the DB.

At present the `Project` object is created successfully, and multiple `ProjectTeam` objects are created successfully, however when adding the `ProjectTeams`, the values for `project` and `team` are null. Furthermore, you see that each `ProjectTeam` object i create a push to an array. Once i've iterated over all teamIds (from the front end), i add the array of `ProjectTeams` to `Project` and update Project.

However, when inspecting the ajax call, I see that a `PUT` request is sent to the appropriate url however, no data is sent whatsoever (`status code 204`)

I have been stuck on this for two days and have exhausted all the resources I managed to find. I am hoping the community will be able to assist me with this one.

Is there another approach of going about this? Have I been fixated into this approach that I haven't considered other approaches? Please give me some guidance, that would be highly appreciated.

EDIT:-----

here are ajax calls and their respective responses:

```
{"project":{"name":"fghfg"}} <- post Project
{"project_teams":[],"project":{"id":3,"name":"fghfg", "created_at":"2014-01-03T12:11:28.372Z","updated_at":"2014-01-03T12:11:28.372Z","project_teams":[]}} <- response

{"project_team":{"sde_effort":34,"project":"3","team":"1"}} <- post ProjectTeam
{"projects":[],"teams":[],"project_team":{"id":2,"sde_effort":34,"created_at":"2014-01-03T12:11:28.494Z","updated_at":"2014-01-03T12:11:28.494Z","project":null,"team":null}} <- response

{"project_teams":[],"team":{"id":1,"name":"Team 1","created_at":"2014-01-03T12:10:42.787Z","updated_at":"2014-01-03T12:10:42.787Z","project_teams":[]}} <- response for GET teams/1

{"project":{"name":"fghfg"}} <- PUT project. No response for this call :/
```

### EDIT 2:

Here's the corresponding data schema in ruby

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20131230144053) do

  create_table "project_teams", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "sde_effort"
    t.integer  "project_id"
    t.integer  "team_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "project_teams", ["project_id"], name: "index_project_teams_on_project_id"
  add_index "project_teams", ["team_id"], name: "index_project_teams_on_team_id"

  create_table "projects", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name",           null: false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "teams", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name",       null: false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

Comment: Could you inspect what params are send in the request? Where does `sdeHeads` come from?

Comment: sdeHeads is an array of values that I collect from the front end. it has got the same length as the array teamIds. I basically iterate over the sdeHeads and use the index to retrieve the teamId and the sdeEffort (since both have the same length) and create a new ProjectTeam object which expects sdeEffort (number), project and team

Comment: I updated my question with the requests sent and their corresponding server responses as well as including the DB schema in ruby

Comment: This may be related http://stackoverflow.com/a/14664991/1234490 :)

Comment: Nope, im returning @project. Do you think the problem may occur because of the table definitions. Because you see for ProjectTeam im expecting project_id and team_id whereas from the frontend i'm sending jsonified objects. I am not sure whether that is a mistake or it is supposed to be like that..

Comment: Ok found the problem. It was nothing ember related.. my attr in the model was project whereas in the database it was project_id.. I'm an idiot! Thanks Thomas you helped a lot mate!